# What's the difference between paper-card and paper-material?

Tags: polymer-1.0

As subject. I found both snippets seem to do the same thing. So when to use which? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the demo of `paper-card`, it's a much fancier version of `paper-material`.
`paper-card` is for holding unique related data. So it has styles for header and contents and actions.
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-card